# My ASP.NET MVC built App is not reading files from User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

The problem is with built ASP.NET MVC solution uploaded on IIS in local network.
When I'm trying to upload file from other device than host, the target page is not loading.
When I'm trying to upload file from host is loading page without data from files.
All works fine when i'm running it in Visual Studio on my pc. The problem was made when i tried to run built solution o Windows Server.

What should I do? It is problem with IIS settings or with wrong code?

```cs
private void ReadFileFromStream(DateChoice datechoice, DateTime dateStartobj, DateTime dateEndobj, string FirstParameter_name, string SecondParameter_name, string ThirdParameter_name, string FourthParameter_name, string FivethParameter_name)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                datechoice.File.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";",
                        HasHeaderRecord = false
                    };

                    ReadCSV(dateStartobj, dateEndobj, streamReader, csvConfig, FirstParameter_name, SecondParameter_name, ThirdParameter_name, FourthParameter_name, FivethParameter_name);
                }
            }
        }

 private void ReadCSV(DateTime dateStartobj, DateTime dateEndobj, StreamReader streamReader, CsvConfiguration csvConfig, string FirstParameter_name, string SecondParameter_name, string ThirdParameter_name, string FourthParameter_name, string FivethParameter_name)
        {
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvConfig))
            {
                var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Read>().ToList();
                List<DataPoint> Parametry_A, Parametry_B, Parametry_C, Parametry_D, Parametry_E;
                NewListDeclarate(out Parametry_A, out Parametry_B, out Parametry_C, out Parametry_D, out Parametry_E);
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    if (DateVerification(record))
                    {
                        DateTime label_date;
                        DataPoint dataPointA, dataPointB, dataPointC, dataPointD, dataPointE;
                        NewPointsGenerate(record, out label_date, out dataPointA, out dataPointB, out dataPointC, out dataPointD, out dataPointE, FirstParameter_name, SecondParameter_name, ThirdParameter_name, FourthParameter_name, FivethParameter_name);
                        if (UserDateCheck(dateStartobj, dateEndobj, label_date))
                        {
                            AddPointsToList(Parametry_A, Parametry_B, Parametry_C, Parametry_D, Parametry_E, dataPointA, dataPointB, dataPointC, dataPointD, dataPointE);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ReturnListsToViewBag(Parametry_A, Parametry_B, Parametry_C, Parametry_D, Parametry_E);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Problem is most likely your `IIS`, `Server` or `network to the server` causing the issue.

Comment: @Marius You are right, mate. I put it on the other server and all works fine.

Comment: It should be a permission issue, do you get any message when you upload files using other device than host?